# HTTP Live streaming not working in JavaFX application

Tags: java, http, javafx, video-streaming

I am trying to create a media-player which plays local media files/media over HTTP live streaming using JavaFX version 2.0.

I am able to play local media files successfully in my media player. But when I try to play media files over HTTP live streaming, then its not working. I am getting white-blank screen as shown below when I try to play media files using HTTP live streaming.

[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viYHC.png)

And following is my code to play media over HTTP live streaming:

```
public class RemoteMultipleFileStreaming extends Application {
    private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://youtu.be/uvcUO8DPWfs?list=PLRQuJcU2aZG-aMedJxa7p7ylYmOn5iMlS&t=2";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();

        Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(500);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(500);

        root.add(mediaView);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please let me know what needs to be done in order to play media files over HTTP live streaming in media player using JavaFX.

Comment: You are trying to stream a HTTPS url instead of a HTTP. JavaFX currently doesn't support HTTPS streaming.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I tried to stream video using HTTP protocol, but still getting the same issue. So please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The url you are using isn't correctly, since it is not directly a mp4 file. You should try something like *http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4*

Answer (score 0):

i think you may need to ebmedd the video html source like this example and run it as html on WebView object

```
    WebView webView= new WebView();
webView.getEngine().loadContent("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/EtwcTIqEOKo\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" +
"", "text/html");
```